# displaying session variables

Tags: php, session

I want to display all session data but have some control over it. the problem is, I can't know exactly what's stored in the session as it's data from a shopping cart.

for example, here one variable in my session:

> item_name_1 : Productname
>   item_quantity_1: 5

each products has some variables with a number. If there were 2 different products in the cart the second one would be

item_number_2 and so on.

there is also a variable called itemcount which tells how many different products are in the cart.

how can I tell php, that all variables that begin with item_name_ should be displayed for example in individual divs after all other variables, like total price?

this is what I use currently to print the session data:

```
<?php
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
echo $key. ": ".$val. "<br>";
?>
```

this is what I see:

> currency: EUR
>   shipping: 10
>   grandTotal: 70.5
>   itemCount: 4
>   item_name_1: Tomato Suppe
>   item_quantity_1: 1
>   item_price_1: 3.5
>   item_options_1:
>   item_name_2: Lentils Suppe
>   item_quantity_2: 14
>   item_price_2: 3.5
>   item_options_2:
>   item_name_3: Chicken Suppe
>   item_quantity_3: 1
>   item_price_3: 4.5
>   item_options_3:
>   item_name_4: Green Leaves Suppe
>   item_quantity_4: 1
>   item_price_4: 3.5
>   item_options_4:

Obviously I want to make it easier to read.

I can use echo $_SESSION['shipping'] for shipping cost to put it wherever I want, but how do I address the products?

say I want every product to be displayed within div and /div for example?

sorry for noob question.

thank you

Comment: You should store every item as seperate arrays. Could you show the code that saves items to session?

Comment: foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
$_SESSION[$k]=$v;
} this is how i convert post data to sessioon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not control the way the data is saved to the session you could write a simple helper function which retrieves the product data in a more usable format.

```
function getSessionProducts()
{
  $itemCount = $_SESSION['itemCount'];
  $products = array(); 
  for($i = 1; $i <= $itemCount; $i++) {
     $products[] = array(
       'name' => $_SESSION['item_name_'.$i],
       'quantity' => $_SESSION['item_quantity_'.$i],
       'price' => $_SESSION['item_price_'.$i],
       'options' => $_SESSION['item_options_'.$i]
    );
  }
  return $products;
}
```

You should of course add proper validation to check if the data in the $_SESSION array is set before accessing it.

Use it as follows

```
$products = getSessionProducts(); 
foreach($products as $product) { 
    echo $product['name']; 
}
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what i need but i cant get it to run for some reason it gives me "unexpected ;" error...

Comment: sorry syntax error within the array declaration. edited the answer.

Comment: try this one again now. I changed the semicolons in the array to commas

Comment: thx, not getting parser error any longer. question, what do i have to do to echo the contents of $product? it gives me undeclared variable error when i put echo $products.

Comment: works like a charm! 10x also, there is a small type one ' missing in ['name'], thx again.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something as crude as this:

```
foreach($_SESSION AS $key => $val)
    if (preg_match("/item_name/i", $key)) {
        echo $val.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Obviously you handle what you do if the match succeeds however you want. This is just to give an idea.

By the way, consider what others are saying. If you are in control of the session vars then it is a better idea to store them in a better, more organized way. This crummy example would work with what you provided though.

Comment: If you're parsing variable names, you're probably doing something wrong

Comment: You're definitely doing something wrong. But he asked how, not how to make it better. I wouldn't use session for this at all.

Comment: this kind of works, but how would i go about combining different things from the same product? this is what i done so far : <?php
foreach($_SESSION AS $key => $val)
    if (preg_match("/item_name/i", $key)) 
        echo '<div>'.$val.'</div>';
   
 ?>
 <?php
foreach($_SESSION AS $key => $val)
    if (preg_match("/item_quantity/i", $key)) 
        echo '<div>'.$val.'</div>';
   
 ?> how could i combine those two?

Comment: figured it out. this actually does exactly what i want 10x

Comment: Fair enough. You should mark one answer as accepted when you can. If it were up to me I'd say dag's answer makes the most sense and is most accessible, so that one should be marked correct. Every other one you found useful should be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start asking yourself "how do I handle variable variable names?" it's a good sign you're heading in the wrong direction.  As you've seen, it's difficult and unnatural to look for `$_SESSION['item_number_$n']`.  What is easy, however, is looping through the contents of an array which, fortunately, you're allowed to store in the session (which, other than how it persists between page loads, it just a normal array).

That is to say that, rather than trying to figure out how to get to `$_SESSION['item_number_5']`, you just look at `$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][5]`.  This makes it easy to iterate through items, count the number of items, add items, remove items and will just be generally cleaner to work with all across the board.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be using session variables to store this kind of information anyway. You should be storing an id to reference a shopping cart within a database in the session rather than storing all of the information about the cart directly in session variables.

Comment: thx, problem is the cart is super simple and doesnt use a database at all, also i dont know anything about databases. i use session to pass the cart data through 2 diferrent checkout pages where you need to fill out a form then the whole thing will be mailed.